# Why doesn't Arqade use it's named URL when other sites like AskUbuntu do?

Tags: discussion, domain-name, stack-exchange

I just realized that [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) is actually a proposed site on Area 51, and I was curious why it got its own URL to be distinguished from others.

Here on Arqade, if I type `https://arqade.com/`, it redirects me to `https://gaming.stackexchange.com/`. Same thing goes for [Ask Different](https://askdifferent.com/).

Why did Ask Ubuntu get its own URL while Arqade can't? Is there a possibility that we will get Arqade (or Ask Different) its own URL?

Comment: I had no idea that `https://arqade.com` even was a valid URL.... Even though it would be very cool to have a fully custom URL, the fact that the redirect exists is interesting in my opinion.

Comment: @Potterton `https://meta.arqade.com` works for this site too. Might help you save some space when [writing comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13530/28182) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu has its own URL primarily because it's the [main source of community support](https://ubuntu.com/support/community-support) for the Ubuntu operating system. That makes it one of the few sites to have its own URL, other than the 'trilogy' (the first three sites, Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User), MathOverflow (which has a [special relation with the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4429/70594)) and Stack Apps (which mostly isn't a real Q&A site anyway).

Arqade/Gaming is already special in that it does have a special URL https://arqade.com/ – they stopped registering those after the first dozen sites.